# NextAuth giving 401 error after hosting website

Tags: authentication, next.js, next-auth

I'm using next-auth credentials provider for authentication in a next.js project, it works fine in development but when I deployed the website to production I got 401 error code with the following response `{url: "https://sub.domain.com/api/auth/error?error="}` as I tried to login.
Everything is working fine in localhost and authentication is smooth with no errors. Wher is the error in my code?
My next-auth config

```js
// /api/auth/[...nextauth].ts
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET ?? 'supersecret',
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: 'admin-login',
      name: 'Admin login',
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: 'Email',
          type: 'email',
          placeholder: 'test@test.com',
        },
        password: { label: 'Mot de passe', type: 'password' },
      },
      authorize: async (credentials, _request) => {
        try {
          const { data: user } = await axios.post(
            `${process.env.APP_URL}/api/auth/admin/login`,
            credentials
          );
          return user;
        } catch (err) {
          throw new Error(
            (err as AxiosError<{ message: string }>).response?.data.message
          );
        }
      },
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: 'room-login',
      name: 'Room login',
      credentials: {
        roomId: { label: 'Id de la chambre', type: 'text' },
        password: { label: 'Mot de passe', type: 'password' },
      },
      authorize: async (credentials, _request) => {
        try {
          const { data: room } = await axios.post(
            `${process.env.APP_URL}/api/auth/room/login`,
            credentials
          );
          return room;
        } catch (err) {
          throw new Error(
            (err as AxiosError<{ message: string }>).response?.data.message
          );
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn() {
      return true;
    },
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      if (url.startsWith('/')) return `${baseUrl}${url}`;
      else if (new URL(url).origin === baseUrl) return url;
      return baseUrl;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
        token.role = (user.role as Role) ?? 'GUEST';
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      const sess: Session = {
        ...session,
        user: {
          ...session.user,
          id: token.id as number | string,
          role: token.role as Role,
        },
      };
      // console.log('SESSION: ', sess)
      return sess;
    },
  },
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET ?? 'supersecret',
    maxAge: 10 * 24 * 30 * 60, // 30 days
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/login',
    signOut: '/auth/login',
    newUser: '/api/auth/register',
    error: '/auth/login',
  },
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
};

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  return NextAuth(req, res, authOptions);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue was caused by the SSL certificate that I had to install on the domain for next-auth to work.